# Checking if document has been created on Cloud Firestore using flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a mobile app using flutter and firebase. I want to create a new document on Cloud Firestore and get the response if the document has been created or not.

If the mobile app does not have internet access, the request is saved, and run when the mobile device is back online. If the mobile is online, I will get a response, if it is not online, I do not get any response.

```
Future<Vote> commitVote(Vote vote) async {

    DocumentReference ref = voteCollection.document(vote.id1+"-"+vote.id2);

    final Map<String, dynamic> data = vote.toMap();

    Vote result = Vote.fromMap(data);
    await ref.setData(data).then((doc) {
      print("doc save successful");
    }).catchError((error) {
      print("doc save error");
      print(error);
    });
    return result;
  }
```

I want to set a timeout for the connection and have the function return true if the document is saved and false if the document has not been saved (when device is offline).

Comment: ref.exists() returns true if the document exists else false

Comment: documentReference.setData(data).whenComplete(() {
      print("Document Added");
    }).catchError((e) => print(e));

Comment: How about [starting a timer locally](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html), and then checking of the completion handler has been called?

Answer (score 1):

```
await ref.setData(data).then((doc) {
      print("doc save successful");
    }).timeout(Duration(seconds:10)).catchError((error) {
      print("doc save error");
      print(error);
    });
```

This will print **doc save error** if the setData transaction doesn't complete within 10 seconds.